# suggest drupal hosting ..i need to test custom shipping module 

Tags: drupal, shared-hosting

suggest shared drupal hosting ..i need to test custom shipping module ....with fedex.

what complicatons may i face with shared hosting like godaddy or hostgator...

Kindly suggest names and who can provide fast support (may be smaller host co)...unlike godaddy where i have to submit ticket and wait for reply for hours...

Answer (score 0):

Hostmonster works great, as well as Lunar Pages.
Hostmonster has great 24/7 support